# Galaxy S6 Active stuck at No Command/Downloading

Tags: rooting, samsung, recovery-mode, custom-roms

**The problem as it stands**

My Galaxy S6 Active is stuck in a sort of bootloop, except it never seems to attempt a boot. If it was turning on, without any combination of keys, it would go to the "No Command" screen. From there all I can do is force reset (power + volume down) to get it to restart to the same place or as it displays the Samsung splash screen, press volume up + power + home, it goes to the download screen. From the download screen, I can use my pc to flash a rom (that may not be correct) to the device and according to Odin, that is a success but my device freezes on "erasing".

[Imgur album with pictures of the accessible screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxvX4.jpg)

**Description of the problem when it was booting**

At seemingly random times, the device would freeze and the only way to get it to do anything was to reset it. Sometimes it would enter a bootloop but through key combinations, I would be able to get it out. One time after a bootloop, I had the sense to back up the device's storage, so luckily I have that.

**What I've done**

- I have tried wiping the storage in device recovery -- when it was accessible, I can no longer get to it.
- I have tried using Kies/Smart Switch emergency software recovery -- but when provided with the model name and serial number they would both crash.
- When the device booted, I tried using the standard recovery feature in Smart Switch. I can't remember the exact message but it was something along the lines of "This device does not support initializing"
- I have tried using Odin to flash ROMs (again, I may be using this incorrectly) to the device. I have only tried Samsung release ROMs, meaning ones that have not been modified by a 3rd party. I followed the second and third methods of [this guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/galaxy-s6-active/downloading-flashing-att-galaxy-s6-t3260744). Odin never throws an error and it always says it was successful. During the device's initilization with this new ROM, it gets to 32% then goes to "Erasing". A few seconds later the animation freezes. I can leave the device here for hours but nothing happens. So I believe more than the animation is frozen.
- I tried using ADB recovery via the device's recovery mode (when it was accessible) but from what I can gather, Samsung uses a proprietary ADB interface that would not work with what I was trying to do (I was following method 3 of the previously mentioned guide (I can't post more than 2 links). I would always get a message saying "ADB server out of date".

I may have done more than that but that's what I can recall.
Any help would be appreciated. Even if you know of a better place to post this, let me know.

Thanks